# How are spacetime diagrams compatible with moving observers measuring shorter lengths?

Tags: special-relativity, reference-frames

I understand that length contraction is a consequence of the relativity of simultaneity. I found this spacetime diagram online:

[image]

Here it's clear that what constitutes a rod for one observer, is a sequence of snapshots of this rod for another observer. Now I have always read the following about length contraction: an observer moving with respect to the rod will measure a shorter length. But according to this diagram, the moving observer who measures the length of the rod along his $x'$ axis, should actually measure a longer length?

Comment: @BenCrowell Someone is fudging your identity.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a visualization of three methods
 
to show that the "length of the rod" $OM$ observed by the moving observer is shorter than the rest length $OL$.

1. Draw **concentric hyperbolas** centered at the left end of the rod.
   The hyperbola corresponding to the rest-length OL is larger than for any other length (such as OM).
    So, $OM < OL$. 
   *What is special about OL is that OL is Minkowski-perpendicular to the worldlines of the rod (that is, the tangent at L is parallel to the worldlines of the rod). 

   The tangent at M is not parallel to the worldlines of the rod.*
2. Using rotated graph paper to help determine the area of "causal diamonds", observe that the **causal diamond with spacelike diagonal OM** has an **area smaller** 
   than that of the diamond with OL. 
   So, $OM < OL$.
3. If you construct the ticks along the axes (with the help of rotated graph paper, where all ticks have the same area), you'll see that $OM < OL$.

[image: LengthContraction-robphy1]

[image: LengthContraction-robphy2]

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: When drawing diagrams like this, one must realize that the scale of the primed axes is not the same as the non-primed. That is, if you measure one centimeter along the $x$ axis and equated that to 1 m, then one centimeter along the $x'$ axis on your piece of paper is **not** 1 m. There is a hyperbolic transform, not a linear one.